# RGB Values retrieved from Pixels incorrect

Tags: ios, objective-c, rgb

I've rendered a circular gradient and created a method that lets me sweep over it with my finger, using a Pan gesture recognizer.

I am retrieving the pixel at my current touch position and want to retrieve it's color.

This means, the color value should constantly update while moving over the gradient.

i'm using the following code :

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {


    CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:iv];
    [sender setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];

    CGPoint center = sender.view.center;
    center.x += translation.x;
    center.y += translation.y;

    sender.view.center = center;
    CGPoint colorPoint = [sender.view.superview convertPoint:center toView:iv];

   [sender setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];





    CGImageRef image = img.CGImage;
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(image);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(image);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    char *rawData = malloc(height * width * 4);
    int bytesPerPixel = 4;
    int bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(
                                                 rawData, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big
                                                 );
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeCopy);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), image);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    int byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * colorPoint.y) + colorPoint.x * bytesPerPixel;
    unsigned char red = rawData[byteIndex];
    unsigned char green = rawData[byteIndex+1];
    unsigned char blue = rawData[byteIndex+2];


    UIColor *hauptfarbe = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0];
    ch.backgroundColor = hauptfarbe;





    NSLog(@"Color value - R : %i G : %i : B %i",red, green, blue);







}
```

this doesn't work as intended, giving me wrong colors and not showing some colors (like red) at all

EDIT : I cannot add a picture yet due to low rep. i will now add the code for rendering the gradient

Code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(size.width, size.height), YES, 0.0);
    [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
    UIRectFill(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height));

    int sectors = 180;
    float radius = MIN(size.width, size.height)/2;
    float angle = 2 * M_PI/sectors;
    UIBezierPath *bezierPath;
    for ( int i = 0; i < sectors; i++)
    {
        CGPoint center = CGPointMake((size.width/2), (size.height/2));
        bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:i * angle endAngle:(i + 1) * angle clockwise:YES];
        [bezierPath addLineToPoint:center];
        [bezierPath closePath];
        UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:((float)i)/sectors saturation:1. brightness:1. alpha:1];
        [color setFill];
        [color setStroke];
        [bezierPath fill];
        [bezierPath stroke];
    }
    img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    [self.view addSubview:iv];
    [self.view addSubview:ch];

}
```

Comment: What color are you expecting and what color are you actually getting?

Comment: i will make an NSLog and paste it in here, one second

Comment: Can't add pictures sadly too low rep. but added the code for the gradient rendering maybe this clears up

Comment: The first problem here is the way you're calculating `colorPoint`. It's always going to be the centerPoint of the view, so you're always going to get the same color back, no matter what.

Comment: can you help me on that?

Comment: @ipmcc your solution is not working with my Pan Gesture recognizer. the user is meant to select the color by dragging over the gradient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem here is the way you're calculating `colorPoint`. They way it is now, `colorPoint` will always be the center point of the view. This `handlePan:` method should get you the point of the last touch in the view:

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if (sender.numberOfTouches)
    {
        CGPoint lastPoint = [sender locationOfTouch: sender.numberOfTouches - 1 inView: sender.view];
        NSLog(@"lastPoint: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(lastPoint));
    }
}
```

From there, I would probably recommend that instead of blitting the image into a bitmap context and then attempting to read back from it at that point, that you just calculate the color for the point using the same mathematical process you used to create the image in the first place. The way you're doing it now is going to be much more CPU + memory intensive.

**EDIT:** Here's what I came up with. It works for me. Starting from the Single View Application template in Xcode, and using the code you posted, I have the following code in ViewController.m:

```
@implementation ViewController
{
    UIImage* img;
    UIImageView* iv;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(size.width, size.height), YES, 0.0);
    [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
    UIRectFill(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height));

    int sectors = 180;
    float radius = MIN(size.width, size.height)/2;
    float angle = 2 * M_PI/sectors;
    UIBezierPath *bezierPath;
    for ( int i = 0; i < sectors; i++)
    {
        CGPoint center = CGPointMake((size.width/2), (size.height/2));
        bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:i * angle endAngle:(i + 1) * angle clockwise:YES];
        [bezierPath addLineToPoint:center];
        [bezierPath closePath];
        UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:((float)i)/sectors saturation:1. brightness:1. alpha:1];
        [color setFill];
        [color setStroke];
        [bezierPath fill];
        [bezierPath stroke];
    }
    img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    [self.view addSubview:iv];
    colorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    colorView.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(bounds) - 25, CGRectGetMaxY(bounds) - 25, 20, 20);
    [self.view addSubview:colorView];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                          initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer: panGesture];    
}

- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if (sender.numberOfTouches)
    {
        CGPoint lastPoint = [sender locationOfTouch: sender.numberOfTouches - 1 inView: sender.view];
        CGRect bounds = self.view.bounds;
        CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds));
        CGPoint delta = CGPointMake(lastPoint.x - center.x,  lastPoint.y - center.y);
        CGFloat angle = (delta.y == 0 ? delta.x >= 0 ? 0 : M_PI : atan2(delta.y, delta.x));
        angle = fmod(angle,  M_PI * 2.0);
        angle += angle >= 0 ? 0 : M_PI * 2.0;
        UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue: angle / (M_PI * 2.0) saturation:1. brightness:1. alpha:1];
        colorView.backgroundColor = color;
        CGFloat r,g,b,a;
        if ([color getRed: &r green: &g blue:&b alpha: &a])
        {
            NSLog(@"Color value - R : %g G : %g : B %g", r, g, b);
        }
    }
}

@end
```

What I see is that as I drag my finger over the gradient, I get a steady stream of messages to console with RGB values that correspond to the location of my finger. I've also added code to show the last color in a small view in the lower right. It also doesn't use bitmap contexts. Hope this helps.

Comment: your method does not work with my pan gesture recognizer, since the user is meant to drag over the gradient with the color constantly updating

Comment: I'm not presenting my method as a complete implementation. I'm trying to help you understand why what you have now doesn't work.

Comment: i understood that, and i also understand that my current approach would be extremely memory intensive. however, numberOfTouches isn't working as i use panning instead of touch.

Comment: It works for me using the code you posted to set up the views, and with the gesture recognizer installed on the main view.

Comment: this is absolutely amazing and exactly what i looked for!

Comment: if i were to display the color currently picked in a rect, how would i do it?

Comment: great! for the sake of not having to open another question. how would i use the fetched UIColor to draw a linear gradient from said color to simple white (brightness adjusting)

Comment: That is a totally different question. Just ask another question - it's free.